# wp_new_user_notification not triggered with wp_insert_user

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a custom plugin to rewrite wp_new_user_notification() as I want, and it's working fine when register a new user from `wp-login.php?action=register` form or `nextend-facebook-connect` plugin.

Also, I've created a custom ajax form to handle registrations from my theme via admin-ajax.php, and every thing is working fine here, except wp_new_user_notification(), I think it's not triggered in this case.

Here is my `register_user` function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_register_user', 'register_user');
function register_user() {
    $user_login = sanitize_user($_POST['user_login']);
    $first_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['last_name']);
    $user_email = sanitize_email($_POST['user_email']);
    $user_pass = $_POST['user_pass'];
    $receive_newsletter = $_POST['receive_newsletter'];

        $userdata = array(
            'user_login' => $user_login,
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name' => $last_name,
            'user_email' => $user_email,
            'user_pass' => $user_pass
        );

        if($user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata)) {
            add_user_meta($user_id, 'receive_newsletter', $receive_newsletter ? 1 : 0);

            echo wp_send_json(array('html' => __('<strong>Congratulations</strong>: Your account is created successfully, please check your email for verification link to activate your account.', 'lh')));
            exit;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function by yourself :

```
if($user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata)) {
   add_user_meta($user_id, 'receive_newsletter', $receive_newsletter ? 1 : 0);

   wp_new_user_notification($user_id,'','both');// <--- here

   echo wp_send_json(array('html' => __('<strong>Congratulations</strong>: Your account is created successfully, please check your email for verification link to activate your account.', 'lh')));
  exit;
}
```

Comment: `wp_new_user_notification()` by itself does not work. You need to use `wp_send_new_user_notifications()`. See my answer below.

Comment: Thank you for this precision. But that's weird because per the docs it does exactly the same thing, except one empty variable : function wp_send_new_user_notifications( $user_id, $notify = 'both' ) {
 wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, null, $notify );
}

Comment: I know it's weird, but it did not work for me today. I'm thinking maybe the `wp_new_user_notification` is being filtered, while the `wp_send_new_user_notifications` is forcing it to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `wp_insert_user()`, you are skipping some hooks and filters, so you need to call the `wp_send_new_user_notifications()` function yourself:

```php
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
    add_user_meta( $user_id, 'receive_newsletter', $receive_newsletter ? 1 : 0 );

    wp_send_new_user_notifications( $user_id, 'both' );

    echo wp_send_json(
        [
            'html' => __( '<strong>Congratulations</strong>: Your account is created successfully, please check your email for verification link to activate your account.', 'lh' ),
        ]
    );

    wp_die();
}
```

See the documentation here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_new_user_notifications/